# Update ACF Field on daily basis

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF field which shows the difference in days between today and the post publish date. The calculation seems to work, because when I add a fixed date, the field changes.

My problem now is that the field does not seem to update automatically each day. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

The code:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();

    $date_created = $order->get_date_created();

    $datetime2 = new DateTime($date_created);

    $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

    $verschil = "difference " . $difference->days . " days ";

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'datum2', $verschil );
```

Comment: Why would you want to _store_ such a value in the first place, why don't you simply dynamically calculate it wherever you need it?

Comment: I am not sure how I should do that. The reason that I want to store it in an acf field is because then I can easily show it on the frond end.

Comment: If the point of all this is to show how many days have passed since the order was created then you should be able to use this exact same code on the front-end (possibly will need some minor tweaks).

Comment: So how could I at this code to a post, and then show the outcome at the frontend. Cause in the end I need to show the post on the front end, with the value included.